# dell optiplex gx280 installing windows 7

Tags: hard-drive

My dell computer has a hard drive capacity of 160GB and came with windows XP.

I updated it to windows 7 but have noticed the c drive is nearly full. There are 3 folders in c drive called Users Windows and Windows old and their sizes are 95gb, 12gb and 7gb. In the users folder there is another folder called public which accounts for the majority of the size.

Any idea what may of happened ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like when you upgraded, you chose the option to save all the data from your WinXP installation. I would look through the Users/Public folder,and the Windows Old Folder, save what you want from it, and delete the rest.